# how to check application installed application in iphone deveice using iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application in which i need to find the apps which are already installed in iphone device such as Skype, facebook. I need to check it using objective -c . Please give me code snippet if possible otherwise a link to get the solution. Is it possible or not.

Thanks in advance ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using any public API's.

Answer (score 7):

Not directly possible using the SDK. If an application you're looking for registers a URL scheme that it can open, then you can check for the presence of that app using the `UIApplication` `-canOpenURL:` method, as documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW50).